# Codebase replication from local workstation to remote server

Tags: linux, windows, workflow, replication, synchronization

We have following structure in our team:

- Using Git with central storage at Bitbucket;
- Using development remote server (Debian), which contains all the code from 'development' branch at the main domain (project.example.com);
- Each developer has his own instance on a server (physically it is a subfolder in document root with symlincs to non-changeable core files of CMF) with his own subdomain (dev01.project.example.com).

What we need is tracking all the local codebase changes in remote instance for each developer.

First most obvious solution is to use **Git** for that - create a remote repository(-ies) on a development server and 'push' changes from local instance to remote. But this is the worst solution, since devs will have to create commits for every single change (including debug messages and all the tries to fix some error output), which will fill Git's log with **tons of useless commits**, so devs will loose all the benefits of local repositories + will have to **spend much time for logs cleaning** before pushing their changes to Bitbucket.

Second option - **local server**. But this also brings issues, since in our structure we all are using single db, so it will bring one more complexity of **replicating remote db and merging it with local changes** too often. Also it will be **hard to replicate the dev environment** on local workstations (Windows based). And I personally dislike the idea of local servers on every machine, since workstation are served for code production, and server - for code work in real environment.

Third option - **FTP sync**. We all are using phpStorm, which has an option of remote sync via FTP. And it works, like a charm, when you change the code and press Ctrl+S - all you changes appear immediately on a remote instance. But, if you pull remote code by Git, you need to **synchronize your local files with remote** ones by FTP - and this runs **too slow** (15-20 mins in our case), because phpStorm compares contents of all the files (we have ~3k php files in our project currently). Sure, we can run comparing by size, but this is non-trustable solution.

Fourth solution - **Samba**. We tried it as well. It was **not much faster, than FTP** with both sub-solutions:

1. sync local files with those, that are located in mounted Samba's drive;
2. work directly on mounted drive

Second one was even worse, since we had internet connection problem and phpStorm hang forever after that...

I also was searching for an existing solutions, but most things, what I found were synchronization utilities, like [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), which must run manually and, actually, it is not, what I looking for - I need not a sync, but **replication utility**, which monitors some local folder and pushes every single changed file (or even better - delta) to a remote location without developer's interaction.

So, devs workflow must be kept as simple, as possible:

- Ctrl+S in IDE replicates on remote;
- git pull replicates on remote;
- git checkout  replicates on remote;
- and so on...

Something, like Dropbox, but with possibility to sync any folder + exclude some sub-folders from replication, and which works one-way only: local -> remote. Which tools may fit our needs?

Comment: I hear this ... This problem drives me nuts.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984986/how-to-reliably-and-quickly-develop-against-a-remote-server-with-a-local-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending one more day to tries and fails, finally I found a tool, that satisfies my needs: [RealSync](https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realsync)
It is not perfect, but does it's job quite good. So, I can advise it for anyone with same problem.

**UPDATE 19.08.13**
Finally I found best solution: we switched to **PhpStorm** IDE, and there is a *Deployment* feature, which allows you to configure deployment servers, map deployment pathes, ignore some files and folders from sync, etc. But most useful option here is located in settings: **Deployment -> Options -> Upload changed files automatically to the default server (Always) + Upload external changes**

This combination makes it possible to drop RealSync and use sync natively from IDE.